# Script shows that Tool is not in a path FATAL error

Tags: shell

When I was running the command in terminal of linux then that command worked and necessary files are created but when I ran that command in shell script then the script is showing the message like "The tool is not in path. FATAL error". Can anyone help me why this is happening when I am running the commands through Shell script?

Command is : /remote/system/vdk/2019.06/bin/icv  -i  -c  -f GDSII | tee drc.log

Is this the problem with tool that it is only running on terminal, but not when we running the same by mean of scripting? Can anyone help me?

Comment: That english text does not line up with the precise text of any error message printed by the shell itself, unless it's a different original language and you're translating. If this `icv` script you run has an error, then its author/maintainer/source are the people to talk to; general shell knowledge isn't sufficient to know which PATH it's looking up, and which tool(s) it's expecting to find there.

Comment: However, *in general*, when something works on the terminal but fails in a different context, you should start by comparing environment variables. Run `env > working.env` in your terminal, and then put something like `env > broken.env` in your script (making the path fully-qualified if necessary), and then compare the two files.

Comment: ...when doing that comparison, I'd look particularly closely at the variable named `PATH` on each side, and any other variables that have `PATH` somewhere in their names.

Comment: To help much more than that, we'd need a [mcve]. (Moreover, questions about how to run a piece of software are not usually on-topic here; our focus is more about questions about how to *write* a piece of software, or fix a specific issue *as one of its authors*).